# How to find execute files in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, directory, system-calls

I wants to get the names of execute files in some directory in Linux.
How can I do it?

I tried to use opendir like this:

> dir = opendir(directoryName);

I need to get only the names of the execute files.
I programming in C.

thanks :)

Comment: There are thousands of examples using [`opendir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) and related functions if you just search a little.

Comment: I search a lot and didn't found anything. Can you help me?

Comment: One of the first hits in my favorite search engines was [this old SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554120/open-directory-using-c). Read that example, read [the manual pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/), and try to make something yourself. ***If*** you have problems with ***your own*** program, then come back here and ask a new question, that shows your complete attempt and a verbose description of your problems with that code.

Comment: after opening, use readdir and stat to get file access rights and determine if it has execution bit set.

Comment: You probably mean *executable files*. "execute file" is bad English! Please edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

You should define what you mean by executable files.

That could be any file with its execute bit (it is the owner, group, or other) set. Then test with [access(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/access.2.html) & `X_OK` and/or use [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html).

That could also be only [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executables. See [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html); then the issue might be to check that a file could indeed be executed, which might be difficult (what about missing library dependencies? or ill-formed ELF files?). Maybe use [libelf](http://www.mr511.de/software/) (and/or [libmagic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmagic/) to do the equivalent of [file(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html) command).

To scan recursively a file tree, use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html); to scan just a directory use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) & [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) (don't forget the `closedir`!), then you'll probably need to build the complete file path from each directory entry (perhaps using [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) or [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html))

See also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)