# How do you run a cmd command in a C program

Tags: c

I couldn't seem to figure out how to run a cmd program in a C program.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char educode[100];
    printf("Welcome To ACE-IT Edu Software!\n");
    printf("\nPlease Type An Educator Code and then press enter.");
    printf("\nEducator Code: ");
    gets(educode);
    if(educode == 5678){
        system("mkdir test");
    } else {
    printf("\nSorry, thats not a valid Educator Code. To buy an Educator Code, go to https://www.ace-it.edu");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never ever use `gets`, this is a deprecated dangerous function that doesn't check the size of the destination. Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: In addition, don't use printf for literal strings. It's pointless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to the bad if-comparison (you can't compare strings with integers) your system call is never run.

Wrong:

```
gets(educode);
if(educode == 5678){
```

Try:

```
gets(educode);
if(strcmp(educode, "5678") == 0 ){
```

Remember to add `#include <string.h>` to the top as well.

Also, never use `gets()` -- it was removed from the C standard in 2011.

Try `fgets()`, after reading up on how to use it.

Comment: I didn't feel like rehashing the always-use-`fgets()` answers with the info about fixing line termination.  But yes, `gets()` is a security risk as a user can type an arbitrary number of characters, overflowing the buffer (`educode` in this case) - and therefore using `gets()` is always wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this code is you are comparing a pointer to a string and an integer, in this line.

```
if (educode == 5678)
```

5678 is an `int` type, and you are determining whether or not it equals a pointer to a string of `chars`. C is an explicitly-typed language, so comparisons like these don't work like that. You will want to use this instead.

```
if (atoi(educode) == 5678)
    system("mkdir test");
```

Use the `stdlib` function [`atoi()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) to convert your string to an integer value.

**Side note:** Using the `system()` function is the same way to run shell commands across all platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac). However, not all of these commands are the same. For instance, what `del` does in DOS-based environments, is `rm` in Linux/Unix. On Windows, you would use `rename` or `move` for the same action that `mv` does on Linux. This program is simple enough, you might just want to use a Batch file, if you're confident this code is only for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you asking for win platform

*you could use the system() function available in process.h to run commands.*

//Program to run dos commands through a C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>

int main()
{
    int choice=0;

    printf("\n***************************************\n");
    printf("1. Open Notepad...\n");
    printf("2. Get Ip Address...\n");
    printf("3. Shut down the computer...\n");

    printf("** Enter your choice :");
    scanf("%d",&choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            system("notepad");
            break;
        case 2:
            system("ipconfig");
            system("pause");
            break;
        case 3:
            system("SHUTDOWN -S");
            system("pause");
            break;
        default:
            printf("\n Invalid choice !!!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: '@Roushan45 et al. you should note that this edit code only applies to Windows systems... and I guess my code below only for Linux...

Comment: i believe he facing issue for windows

Comment: I couldn't say for sure whether I believe it, but clang really dislikes using scanf to parse an integer. It doesn't check for failure. strtol is more rubust.

Comment: commented the #include <process.h>. still worked for me. Can you tell me why do i need process.h ??

Answer (score 0):

Try the solution in this link:

[Calling 'ls' with execv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507950/calling-ls-with-execv)

Make these changes:

```
args[0] = "/bin/mkdir" 
args[1] = "new_directory"
```