# closedir causing munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, visual-studio-code, directory, closedir

So, I was doing an exercise that prevedes to open a directory and save his files to use them for other functions. The code is:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%sApro la cartella salvataggi%s\n", COL_YELLOW, COL_GRAY);

    int i = 0;
    int initsaves = 10;
    char **saveFiles = (char **)malloc(initsaves * sizeof(char *));
    int dim = initsaves - 1;

    DIR *saveDir;

    errno = 0;

    if ((saveDir = opendir(pathSaves)) == NULL)
    {
        if (errno == ENOENT)
            mkdir(pathSaves, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG | S_IRWXO);
        else
        {
            printf("%i\n", errno);
            errExit("Error in opening savefile");
        }
    }

    struct dirent *controlSaves = readdir(saveDir);

    do
    {
        if (i == dim - 1)
        {
            dim *= 2;
            saveFiles = (char **)realloc(saveFiles, dim);
        }

        if (strncmp(controlSaves->d_name, ".", 1) != 0)
        {
            saveFiles[i] = controlSaves->d_name;
            printf("%s\n", saveFiles[i]);
            i++;
        }

        controlSaves = readdir(saveDir);
    } while (controlSaves != NULL);

    free(saveFiles);

    if (closedir(saveDir) == -1)
    {
        errExit("Problema nel chiudere la cartella");
    }

    printf("%sFINITO%s\n", COL_RED, COL_GRAY);
    return 0;
}
```

Other information, `pathSave` is defined as "/Salvataggi". In WSL it works.

Now, while I was doing the exercise, the terminal gave me a munmap chunk error. I've done some text, but only deleting the closedir() I could eliminate the error. Now, I don't want let open the directory after the end of the program, and I want to know why should be the closedir to cause a pointer error.

Also, I use Visual Studio Code. I have windows, so I use WSL for the system calls.

PS: Sorry for my english

Comment: Where is `pathSaves` defined?

Comment: ...does `pathSaves` contain an actual directory?

Comment: Compare what you are doing with [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554120/open-directory-using-c)

Comment: (By the way, I see you are new here. Welcome!   May I suggest that when you post, it is a good idea to hang around for a few minutes to respond to questions, comments, etc.)

Comment: This statement is called: `saveFiles[i] = controlSaves->d_name;` before allocating memory to `savesFiles[i]`.  You should have seen compile-time warnings and errors with this code.  This indicates what you have posted is not the code you actually ran.

Comment: pathsaves is defined in un header file. Contain the directory to analize. The definition is simply "/Salvataggi"

Comment: ```saveFiles[i] = controlSaves->d_name;``` is not called before allocating memory. But it can be called before the realloc, if you mean that.

Comment: Read my previous comment and edit your post please.   By the way, `"/Salvataggi"` is a linux style directory, but you said you are using Windows?

Comment: `saveFiles` is allocated memory, but `saveFiles[i]` is not. (I don't see where you do it in your post anyway.)

Comment: No, it's not. Because it works as a pointer to string, like  ```char *string = "content";```

Comment: After `char **saveFiles = (char **)malloc(initsaves * sizeof(char *));` use something like: `if(saveFiles) { for(i=0 ; i<numPointers;i++) { initSaves[i] = malloc(numPointer*sizeofSpaceNeededInEach);}`